# Mobile Device ID Recognizing

Tags: dom

Somehow, my current operator recognizes my iPhone serial number or something. I think this is the cookie for it:

```
cookie: _uid35166
value: E9B00FAC.1
```

I'm wondering how a web page can recognize something about the mobile phone?
Is this the serial number and in what language it can be done?

Comment: You ask what language, but you tag the post with PHP and JS. What is the actual intent? Are you wanting an answer in that language?

Comment: Your operator is also your service provider, so they have access to info like this. You'll probably find that with cookies cleared, it can't recognise you if you connect via wifi

Comment: Also yeah, this has nothing whatsoever to do with javascript, php, or the dom

Comment: Yes, I'm just not sure in which language it's possible to be done.

Comment: Yeah, because they're checking the connection itself. It is 100% impossible (for very good security & privacy reasons) for anybody except the service provider to do this.

Comment: Alright, can anyone tells me which exactly iPhone information is this? I've checked, it's not IMEI or Serial Number. When I open the page from my computer, using chrome, the value is different: F4255F38.1.

Comment: You mean the "value" you posted? It's just your session ID for that website. Nothing special, or device-dependent. (Look up session cookies if you want more info). If you clear cookies and visit the site again on the same device, you'll get a new one.

Comment: network providers themselves can check your connection or device specific values because they are providing the connection, but even they can't achieve this via simple web based systems. They have to query whatever backend system they have to figure all these values. But because they have access to the backend system, their web server can get this info and serve you accordingly...